# Intercept envelope from SOAP request

Tags: php, soap, envelope

For debugging purposes I'd like to see what SOAP request and responses are send back and forth between a SoapClient and SoapServer.

I remember seeing once that some methods on the instances of SoapServer or SoapClients were able to trace this SOAP messages. Is this really possible? Or some other way to able to see the SOAP envelopes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

soapUI is indeed a valuable tool. You may also find [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) useful, and you can use the debugging features of php's soap api. Eg. [`getLastRequestHeaders`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequestheaders.php), [`getLastRequest`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php) and the corresponding [`getLastResponseHeaders`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponseheaders.php), [`getLastResponse`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php)

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/), its a realy great tool for testing soap-services.

Comment: Allright, will have a look sometime. Can't use it at this moment, but can be useful indeed!

Answer (score 1):

The SoapClient class has these methods:

```
public string __getLastRequest ( void )
public string __getLastRequestHeaders ( void )
public string __getLastResponse ( void )
public string __getLastResponseHeaders ( void )
```

referenced from: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php